# Append text between li's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery function would append the text between the li's to a div("#title").

something like

```
$(function () {
    $("#videos li a").click(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', 'active');
          $('#title').text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

but it appends the id "active" to the li clicked on, and is removed when clicked on another.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your markup is invalid. You are missing `</li>`.

Comment: Where is your jQuery function?

Comment: exactly what you want ?

Comment: I'm trying to find a method that retrieves the text in between the two li's.

Comment: $('ul#menu li a').text();

Comment: Rolled back your last edit because it broke all answers.

Comment: Finally got it.

$(function () {
    $("#videos a li").click(function() {
  $('#active').removeAttr("id");
  $(this).attr('id', 'active');
    $('#title').text($(this).text());
 });
});

Comment: @undefined: `</li>` is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your document.ready handler:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){
    $('#examplediv').text($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the value and put it in inside the div

```
$("#examplediv").html( $("#menu>li>a").html());
```

[click here for jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/9w8Ah/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul#menu li').text('My Text');
})
```

and your html should be like this

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="">real</a></li>
</ul>
```

bec it is broken in your question

Answer (score 0):

To get text in `li`:

```
$('ul#menu li a').text()
```

Comment: @asdf No, "An li element’s end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element." ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html))

Comment: He has 'a' tag inside li, text() method will bring undefined.

Comment: It's not invalid, just "optional". It's better practice to close your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu-li"><a href="">real</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="examplediv"></div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#examplediv").text($("#menu-li").text());
})
```

Comment: @IswantoSan, I don't think u had to introduce an 'id' to select it. Obviously, it is not wrong but it can be selected by countless other methods.